# Hide the empty field data that is showing undefined in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

i want hide the data of the empty fields that are shown in console as undefined. please explain your answer as am new to angular .

thanks in advance.

[image]

[image: this is my component]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Why would it matters if the field display undefined in your console? What is your use case here? In your application you should be checking if it's undefined/null before displaying it anyways.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode - Hey Siddharth and welcome on SO! Unfortunately while you provided code, you posted it as image making it impossible for others to quickly take a look at or play with it. It is rather unlikely that somone will type the code char by char from your image so to increase your chances of getting an answer, post the code in your question. Ideally make it an [mcve]. For more information visit the link above.

Comment: i want to pass only the values that are entered and hide everything else

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can check variable's value before logging on console;

let I have a variable  `let temp;`

just use ternary `console.log(temp?temp:'')`

So, here if 'temp' is defined it will print the value of `temp` else it will print nothing.

Comment: i have tried this, but the values are printed as undefined when field is left blank